# Solving simultaneous equations such as $\begin{cases} x+\sin(\theta)=c \\ dx+\cos(\theta)=e \end{cases}$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

> > Hi, I've been doing quite a lot questions for engineering statics where I have to solve simultaneous equations like this

$$\begin{cases} x+\sin(\theta)=c \\ 
 dx+\cos(\theta)=e \end{cases}$$

where $x$ is a variable and $c,d,e \in R$ are constants

Obviously we can use a familiar trig identity:

$$\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$$

$$ (c-x)^2+(e-dx)^2 =1 $$ and solve for $x$ then $\theta$ but then that process in an exam is quite tedious so I was wondering if there is a different way of solving these types of simultaneous equations where there is are 2 variables however one variable is inside a trig function.

Comment: If this specific form comes up a lot, consider programming your calculator to have a function that computes the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You've already covered the option to eliminate $\theta$; you could also opt to eliminate $x$, leaving behind the equation

$$ d \sin(\theta) - \cos(\theta) = dc - e $$

A general trick worth knowing if you do a lot of manipulations with trig functions is how to combine a linear combination of $\sin$ and $\cos$: the key is to use the identity

$$ \sin(\theta + \phi) = \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) + \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) $$

and you want to rewrite the constants of the linear combination with $\phi$. You need to rescale so the coefficients satisfy the pythagorean law, so

$$ a \sin(\theta) + b \cos(\theta) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin\left( \theta + \phi \right) $$

where $\phi$ is chosen so that

- $\cos(\phi) = a / \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$
- $\sin(\phi) = b / \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$

Of course, this means $\tan(\phi) = b/a$, but when you take the arctangent, you have to take care to make sure the angle you choose lies in the correct quadrant.

The end result is that the original equation is now of the form

$$ R \sin(\theta + \phi) = S $$

which you can solve in a straightforward fashion.

(you can do a similar trick with $\cos$, if you prefer taking arccosines rather than arcsines)